# Spring Boot NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I am converting a Java EE project to Spring Boot 1.1.9. Before converting, I was used to CDI 1.2 for Dependency Injection.

I have an interface :

```
public interface AdminManager<V extends AdminView>
```

I also have a few implementations of this interface. They look like this :

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class DBRuleManager implements AdminManager<AdminRuleView>

@Repository
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class DBFlagLogicManager implements AdminManager<AdminFlagLogicView>
```

Now, I have coded a REST endpoint, that is supposed to use the `DBRuleManager`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/rule")
public class RestAdminRule {

    @Inject
    private AdminManager<AdminRuleView> manager;

}
```

When I run `mvn spring-boot:run` I get the following `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.server.admin.AdminManager] is defined: expected single matching but found 2: DBRuleManager,DBFlagLogicManager
```

I've read that Spring 4 is supposed to manage this kind of situation. What's the problem then? This was working well using CDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to solve another problem (about proxies for `@Transactional` implementations), I found a way to get rid of this issue.
I used this parameter :

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

And then I was able to inject my `AdminManager<AdminRuleView>` directly. I don't understand why, though...

Comment: the `proxyTargetClass` attribute defines what kind of proxy Spring will use for dependency injection or AOP. There are two of them, the JDK one and CGLib. CGLib is more powerful as it enables concrete classes injection and not only classes hidden behind interfaces. `proxyTargetClass` enables CGLib. I seems to have nothing to do with our problem, but I think CGLib is also more powerful for reflection and makes our case work too. It is just not documented enough.